# Python Faust Tumbling Window not working when using relative_to_field

Tags: python-3.x, faust

When the tumbling window used along with relative_to_field it is not working as expected. The values updated against a key itself are not getting reflected in the same window. It always returns the default value instead of the updated value. When I am not using "relative_to_field" it is working as expected.

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta

import faust

class Count(faust.Record, serializer='json'):
    user: str = ""
    count: int = 0
    timestamp: float = 0

count_schema = faust.Schema(
    key_type=str,
    value_type=Count,
    # key_serializer='str',
    value_serializer='json'
)

app = faust.App("Test_windowed_new", broker="localhost:9092", store='rocksdb://')
count_topic = app.topic("count_topic", schema=count_schema)


def window_processor(key, event):
    print("Windowing event 1 : {}".format(key[0]) + "Event " + str(event))

tumbling_table = (
    app.Table(
        "test_table_diff_new",
        default=Count,
        key_type=str,
        value_type=Count,
        partitions=1,
        on_window_close=window_processor,
    ).tumbling(5, key_index=True, expires=timedelta(seconds=5)).relative_to_field(Count.timestamp)
)


@app.agent(count_topic)
async def count_message(msgs):
    async for key,msg in msgs.items():
        print("incoming message  "+str(msg) +" for key " + key)
        windowSet = tumbling_table[key]
        prev_count = windowSet.value()
        count=  Count()
        count.count = msg.count + prev_count.count
        count.user=msg.user
        count.timestamp = msg.timestamp
        tumbling_table[key]= count
        print("Going to update :: " + str(count) + " for key " + key + "for log_time_in_sec  " + str(msg.timestamp))
        print("Value after update :: " + str(tumbling_table[key].value()) + " for key " + key)



@app.timer(interval=1.0,  on_leader=True)
async def send_count_kafka():
    count = Count()
    count.user = "test"
    count.count = 100
    count.timestamp =time.time()
    await count_message.send(
        key=str(count.user),
        value=count
    )
    print('Count Message :: send messge')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Test Application getting started")
    app.main()
```

### Expected behavior

Below Print statement where we are printing the latest value from the tumbling window after the update should return the value which has been updated in the previous step
"Value after update :: " + str(tumbling_table[key].value()) "

```
[2021-04-02 17:52:43,709] [29841] [WARNING] Value after update :: <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1617366163.204891>  for key test
```

### Actual behavior

Below Print statement where we are printing the latest value from the tumbling window after the update is giving the default value instead of the updated value
"Value after update :: " + str(tumbling_table[key].value()) "

```
[2021-04-02 17:52:43,698] [29841] [WARNING] incoming message  <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1617366163.204891> for key test 
[2021-04-02 17:52:43,709] [29841] [WARNING] Going to update :: <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1617366163.204891> for key test for log_time_in_sec  1617366163.204891 
[2021-04-02 17:52:43,709] [29841] [WARNING] Value after update :: <Count: user='', count=0, timestamp=0> for key test
```

## Versions

- Python version : 3.8.8
- Faust version : v1.10.4
- Operating system : OSX  Big Sur 11.2.3
- Kafka version : kafka_2.12-2.3.0
- RocksDB version : 0.7.0

I am not sure why this simple code is not working when using relative_to_field option along with tumbling window.

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is your desired output? Because that's what I get with your Code from Above. Only difference is that I am using Ubuntu.

```
[2021-04-13 10:36:14,106] [953605] [INFO] [^Worker]: Ready 
[2021-04-13 10:36:15,109] [953605] [WARNING] Count Message :: send message 
[2021-04-13 10:36:15,608] [953605] [WARNING] incoming message  <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1618302975.108263> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:15,610] [953605] [WARNING] Going to update :: <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1618302975.108263> for key test for log_time_in_sec  1618302975.108263 
[2021-04-13 10:36:15,610] [953605] [WARNING] Value after update :: <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1618302975.108263> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:16,110] [953605] [WARNING] Count Message :: send message 
[2021-04-13 10:36:16,114] [953605] [WARNING] incoming message  <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1618302976.1102037> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:16,114] [953605] [WARNING] Going to update :: <Count: user='test', count=200, timestamp=1618302976.1102037> for key test for log_time_in_sec  1618302976.1102037 
[2021-04-13 10:36:16,114] [953605] [WARNING] Value after update :: <Count: user='test', count=200, timestamp=1618302976.1102037> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:17,112] [953605] [WARNING] Count Message :: send message 
[2021-04-13 10:36:17,121] [953605] [WARNING] incoming message  <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1618302977.1120646> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:17,121] [953605] [WARNING] Going to update :: <Count: user='test', count=300, timestamp=1618302977.1120646> for key test for log_time_in_sec  1618302977.1120646 
[2021-04-13 10:36:17,121] [953605] [WARNING] Value after update :: <Count: user='test', count=300, timestamp=1618302977.1120646> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:18,114] [953605] [WARNING] Count Message :: send message 
[2021-04-13 10:36:18,120] [953605] [WARNING] incoming message  <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1618302978.1135106> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:18,121] [953605] [WARNING] Going to update :: <Count: user='test', count=400, timestamp=1618302978.1135106> for key test for log_time_in_sec  1618302978.1135106 
[2021-04-13 10:36:18,122] [953605] [WARNING] Value after update :: <Count: user='test', count=400, timestamp=1618302978.1135106> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:19,116] [953605] [WARNING] Count Message :: send message 
[2021-04-13 10:36:19,119] [953605] [WARNING] incoming message  <Count: user='test', count=100, timestamp=1618302979.1159449> for key test 
[2021-04-13 10:36:19,120] [953605] [WARNING] Going to update :: <Count: user='test', count=500, timestamp=1618302979.1159449> for key test for log_time_in_sec  1618302979.1159449 
[2021-04-13 10:36:19,120] [953605] [WARNING] Value after update :: <Count: user='test', count=500, timestamp=1618302979.1159449> for key test
```